# Clamdscan error when launched by apache user "No file descriptor received. ERROR"

Tags: apache-2.4, centos7, clamav

We're trying to use clamav on a centos 7 server in order to scan directly files on our web apps (Moodle for example).
When trying to execute a clamdscan from apache, we got this error (the file belong to apache:apache and has correct rights 755)

```
<?php
exec('/usr/bin/clamdscan --stdout --fdpass /var/www/html/test/filetoscan', $output, $return);
print "<pre>";
print_r($output);
print_r($return);
?>
```

And the return is :

```
Array
(
[0] => Failed to parse reply: "No file descriptor received. ERROR"
[1] => 
[2] => ----------- SCAN SUMMARY -----------
[3] => Infected files: 0
[4] => Total errors: 1
[5] => Time: 0.000 sec (0 m 0 s)
)
2
```

Of course, if we try to do it directly through command lines, we have same error..

```
su -l apache -s /bin/bash
/usr/bin/clamdscan --stdout --fdpass /var/www/html/test/filetoscan
```

How can I allow apache to execute clamdscan (or resolve the file descriptor problem) ? of course if the command is launched by an other user everything works fine.

Thanks for your help :-)

Regards.
Diego

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neither applying `setsebool -P antivirus_can_scan_system 1` (from [this setup procedure](http://linux-audit.com/install-clamav-on-centos-7-using-freshclam/)) or disabling completely SELinux in `/etc/selinux/config` have improved the situation.

As a result, a `strace` has been generated to understand what happens, running as `apache`:

```
$ strace /usr/bin/clamdscan --stdout --fdpass /var/www/html/cours/moodledata/temp/filetoscan
[...]
rt_sigaction(SIGPIPE, {SIG_IGN, [PIPE], SA_RESTORER, 0x7ff93f13c650}, NULL, 8) = 0
lstat("/var/www/html/cours/moodledata/temp/filetoscan", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=7256, ...}) = 0
socket(PF_LOCAL, SOCK_STREAM, 0)        = 3
connect(3, {sa_family=AF_LOCAL, sun_path="/var/run/clamd.scan/clamd.sock"}, 110) = -1 EACCES (Permission denied)
close(3)                                = 0
socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP) = 3
connect(3, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(3310), sin_addr=inet_addr("127.0.0.1")}, 16) = 0
open("/var/www/html/cours/moodledata/temp/filetoscan", O_RDONLY) = 4
sendto(3, "zFILDES\0", 8, 0, NULL, 0)   = 8
sendmsg(3, {msg_name(0)=NULL, msg_iov(1)=[{"\0", 1}], msg_controllen=20, {cmsg_len=20, cmsg_level=SOL_SOCKET, cmsg_type=SCM_RIGHTS, {4}}, msg_flags=0}, 0) = 1
close(4)                                = 0
recvfrom(3, "No file descriptor received. ERR"..., 5120, 0, NULL, NULL) = 35
fstat(1, {st_mode=S_IFCHR|0620, st_rdev=makedev(136, 0), ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7ff93fd3b000
write(1, "Failed to parse reply: \"No file "..., 60Failed to parse reply: "No file descriptor received. ERROR"
```

First accessing the unix socket file `/var/run/clamd.scan/clamd.sock` failed, then the fallback to TCP communication `127.0.0.1/3301` failed for another reason.

Probably adding `apache` in the required group to access the unix socket will fix your issue.

Answer (score 2):

edit /etc/clamd.conf to configure Unix user clamav should run under:
    User apache

Fix file/directory permissions:
    chown -R apache:apache /var/run/clamd.scan; 
    chown apache:apache /var/run/clamd.scan/clamd.sock

Otherwise clamav will by default run as user clamscan, which doesn't have permissions to access this file, even though you added --fdpass as an argument to the scan.

Comment: Thank you so much. This socket permission problem has been driving me crazy for hours. I am calling clamdscan from Tomcat and simply setting the socket parent directory to tomcat:tomcat suddenly made everything work!